# How to change request ContentType to test/xml while using Message.CreateMessage

Tags: message, content-type

From a .NET 3.5 assembly, I'm creating a Message object via Message.CreateMessage

```
Message msgInput = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressing10, "QueryRequest", new XmlNodeReader(myPayloadDoc));
```

When executing the query, this defaultly sets the ContentType to "application/soap + xml" but I need it to be "text/xml". I know I'm fundamentally missing something here and it probably starts with the MessageVersion I have selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to implement a custom binding using the WCF examples for customTextMessageEncoder.

```
<customTextMessageEncoding mediaType="text/xml" messageVersion="Soap11" />
```